# Why does this small program not crash?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

In the program below, if I enter "sbsbsbsbssbsbsbsbsbsbsbsbsbsbs" or even more characters, this program works and prints the value. Can someone please explain why?

```
int main()
{
 char *s = strdup("");
 scanf("%s",s);

 printf("\nInput:\t%s\n",s);
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Because it hasn't broken anything (yet). I threw a tomato at the window. Why didn't it break?

Comment: Essentially: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why

Comment: It's because of something called _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Side note: `free(s);` after the scanf is I think likely to break if you've written enough data in there.

Comment: there is no rule that says: When you cross a red light you will be hit by a car. There is a rule that says: Do not cross red lights. Similar here, speciftying what happens when you compile and and run wrong code would be rather pointless, because we care about correct code that has well defined behavior. Yours has undefined behavior

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the comments